# Remove MS deploye warning "exited with code 0x0"

Tags: msdeploy

In runCommand of MSDdeploy, we get following warning

> Warning: The process 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe' (command line '') exited with code '0x0'.

The command is

```
Package\OurProject.csproj.deploy.cmd 
  [some other options] 
  "-postSync:runCommand='powershell -inputformat none c:\AfterDeploy.ps1'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add parameter successReturnCodes, e.g. successReturnCodes=0.

e.g.

```
Package\OurProject.csproj.deploy.cmd 
  [some other options] 
  "-postSync:runCommand='powershell -inputformat none c:\AfterDeploy.ps1',successReturnCodes=0"
```

See [Web Deploy runCommand Provider](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)